# Does having a Free Press improve the national unity gain caused by domestic spies?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

If I am trying to increase **National Unity** by employing domestic spies, does the +20% increase caused by having a **Free Press** have a beneficial effect? The value is shown in red, indicating an undesirable effect, but the text is as follows:

> *The size of changes is modified by: **Free Press: 20%***

This suggests that increases are affected as well as decreases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. The changes shown in red appear to be bad but are good if you want to change the value significantly.